# Template function that supports references, values, and pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, pointers, reference

I'm wrapping a C function in a C++ function. The C function accepts a function pointer (with state). I want to allow a C++ callable. A code sample says a thousand words so...

```cpp
//======================================================
// All this stuff is defined in C somewhere else

// C string type
typedef struct FooString { const char* str; size_t length; } FooString;

// C function pointer type
// This keeps getting called until it returns something with length == 0
typedef FooString (*CFunctionPointer)(void* state);

// Function being wrapped
void quux(CFunctionPointer fPtr, void* state)
{
    FooString str;
    while(1)
    {
        str = fPtr(state);
        if(str.length == 0)
            break;
        else
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}

//======================================================
// Here's what I need help with

template<typename IteratorFunctor>
void quuxWrapper(IteratorFunctor& iterator) const
{
    // type that the functor returns, and related types
    using TIn = decltype(iterator());
    using TNoRef = typename std::remove_reference<TIn>::type;
    using TYesRef = typename std::add_lvalue_reference<TNoRef>::type;
    using TStored = typename std::conditional<std::is_reference<TIn>::value, std::reference_wrapper<TNoRef>, TIn>::type;

    // store this on the stack in this function, and pass a pointer to it into the C library
    // the C callback will pass back the pointer, and we can get at all this stuff from within the lambda
    struct CallbackContext
    {
        bool isFirst;               // is this the first iteration?
        IteratorFunctor& iterator;  // reference to the iterator in a place we can get to from inside the C function pointer callback
        TStored current;            // current value (either an actual value stored on the stack, or a reference wrapper)
    };

    CFunctionPointer cFunctionPtr = [](void* pContext) -> FooString
    {
        CallbackContext& context = *((CallbackContext*) pContext);

        // on the first iteration, we return the value already fetched (need to do this to support things that
        // aren't DefaultConstructable). On subsequent iterations, call the functor again.
        if(context.isFirst)
            context.isFirst = false;
        else
            context.current = context.iterator();

        // this is needed for supporting both references as reference_wrappers and value types. we take a reference
        // which forces reference_wrapper to call its conversion operator and is basically a no-op for value types
        // (something like context.current.length would fail for reference_wrapper)
        TYesRef current = context.current;

        // stop iteration if functor returns anything with length 0
        if(current.length() == 0)
            return FooString{nullptr, 0};
        else
            return FooString{current.data(), current.length()};
    };

    // create the context and make the first call to the iterator
    CallbackContext context{true, iterator, iterator()};

    // and then call the C function
    quux(cFunctionPtr, &context);
}
```

This supports returning a `std::string` or `std::string&` from the functor. It also allows users to return their own type, as long as that type has `length()` and `data()` methods. It doesn't allow the functor to return a `std::string*`, though, which is what I'd like to support.

Is there a good way to do this using C++11 features (and no dependencies or weird compiler hacks, since this is part of the public API)?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but that just reminds me of the famous [fliewatüüt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbi,_Tobbi_und_das_Fliewat%C3%BC%C3%BCt)

Comment: So you are basically creating an `std::invoke` like wrapper for a c-style function that accepts a pointer to void as context to invoke callbacks? This example seems to be rather large yet far from complete.

Comment: @VTT yes, I guess that's one way to put it. In what way do you find this incomplete? I'll add the definitions of the C stuff, although it shouldn't be that important.

Comment: It is not clear which requirements are inflicted on `IteratorFunctor` parameter. or how do you call this function template. Some variables, such as `temp` or `db` emerge out of thin air. When you write "So this supports functors that return either references or value types" it is not clear whether you refer to C function being wrapped or to C++ callable. Also this template seem to wrap some C entities into `MatchCollection` class.

Comment: @VTT Let me go ahead and remove all the specific stuff and put some foos and bars in so that the distracting stuff is no longer there.

Comment: So, AFAICT, the problematic part is `FooString{current.data(), current.length()};`, nothing else?

Comment: @jrok yes, that's the part that will break if the functor returns a pointer.

Comment: I am not seeing obvious ownership rules.  You have a `char const*` and now a `std::string*`.  Who owns what, what are the lifetimes?

Comment: @Yaak - That's the point of allowing it to return values. If the caller wants to return a value type, that will be stored on the stack. If the caller wants to return a std::string& or std::string* they can maintain ownership. This is an API function, so I want it to be as general as possible for any use case.

Comment: @RobertFraser Value types won't last past the wrapping function's invokation.  By the time you return a `FooString` it is too late.  Again, **who owns the `const char*`** -- that should be defined by the C API.

Comment: @Yaak - I know. That's the point. The C function uses the const char* only until the next call to the function pointer. The "ownership" of it is entirely on the stack. Ultimately, I don't see how that's relevant though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class F, class R=std::result_of_t<F&()>>
struct c_callback {
  F state;
  void* get_pvoid() { return std::addressof(state); }
  using C_sig = R(*)(void*);
  static C_sig get_pfunc() {
    return [](void* pvoid)->R {
      F* pstate = static_cast<F*>(pvoid);
      return static_cast<R>( (*state)() );
    };
  }
};
```

this wraps a lambda or other C++ invokable into a function pointer and pvoid.  It does nothing else.  The return value is either deduced or passed.

Your second problem is wanting to adapt return values.

```
template<class T>
FooString to_foostring_f( T& t ) {
  return {t.data(), t.length()};
}
template<class T>
FooString to_foostring_f( T* t ) {
  if (!t) return {0,0};
  return to_foostring_f(*t);
}

auto to_foostring = [](auto&& t)->FooString {
  return to_foostring_f( decltype(t)(t) );
};
```

`to_foostring` is a function object that takes something, and returns a `FooString`.  It does this by calling `to_foostring_f`.  You can enhance it with ADL.

Finally write `compose(First, Second)` which returns `Second(First(Args...))`.

Stitch these together and it should work.

Comment: This isn't exactly the same because it doesn't keep a copy of the most recently returned value (so it won't support value types). But it's easy to adapt. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertFraser That copy can be stored within the function object stored in `c_callback`.